# Ruby Soap Web Service not supported in Visual studio error

Tags: ruby, web-services, visual-studio-2010, soap, soapui

Visual studio getting an error when adding the soap web reference

```
the document at the url was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be <schema> and its namespace should be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL could not be found.'.
  - The document format is not recognized.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (2, 55).'.
  - The string '' is not a valid Uri value.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.
```

This is the content that is being returned:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="m:BillServiceSoap">
   <soap:Body>
      <tns:S3rdParty_PaymentRs>
         <PaymentRs xsi:type="tns:bill_payment_service_soap_types.payment_rs">
            <ChannelID xsi:type="xsd:string">1</ChannelID>
            <ResponseCode xsi:type="xsd:string">2</ResponseCode>
         </PaymentRs>
      </tns:S3rdParty_PaymentRs>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: So what have you tried to solve this? Obviously, your web service is not working properly

Comment: @NicoHaase  I have tried with Soup UI and it's working. that is the problem i am having , what would be the reason to not working with VS

Comment: According to the error message, the content type is not set properly. Is it possible that Soup UI ignores this, while your own code is more strict?

Comment: @NicoHaase. yes. It's confusing

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:ruby]? Can you post some part of what SoapUI returns?

Comment: @engineersmnky,  Soap UI returns a response in XML. it's status in HTTP/1.1 200. I have mentioned Ruby since I don't know whether it requires any special ways to handle Visual studio with Ruby.

Comment: Kevin I understand that Soap returns XML can you post an actual example of the response

Comment: @engineersmnky- <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="m:BillServiceSoap">
   <soap:Body>
      <tns:S3rdParty_PaymentRs>
         <PaymentRs xsi:type="tns:bill_payment_service_soap_types.payment_rs">
            <ChannelID xsi:type="xsd:string">1</ChannelID>
            <ResponseCode xsi:type="xsd:string">2</ResponseCode>
         </PaymentRs>
      </tns:S3rdParty_PaymentRs>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>